# DNS through socks proxy. How do I change windows settings for domain resolution.

Tags: ssh, proxy, dns, tor, socks

I am looking for a program to reroute windows domain resolution lookup through a socks proxy capable with many internet browsers and internet proxies.

So far in Control Panel, Local Area Connection 1, TCP/IP Properties, I use the following DNS server addresses, preferred DNS Server, I put 127.0.0.1 and use the default in-built port request 53.

I am reading that it is possible to forward this. I can not find a program to forward it through socks 4/5. I think this is possible because Socks supports UDP.

Has anyone come up with the answer to a solution about a UDP-to-socks forwarding program capable and adapted for socks and windows DNS.

Answer (score 7):

It's really quite easy to configure.

You could write your own server and set the server to listen to incoming calls to port 53 or use this program

http://dns2socks.sourceforge.net

here my sample configuration for a socks server running on 1050 and TCP / IP settings on 127.0.0.1

DNS2SOCKS.exe /la:socks.log 127.0.0.1:1050 8.8.8.8:53 127.0.0.1:53

Answer (score 0):

For such a program you can have a look at [dnsadblock](https://dnsadblock.com). Their free daemon/cli app opens up a proxy server that can be configured to use a proxy/socks to communicate with the upstream server. It works since the remote endpoint listens on https which makes DOH (dns over https) possible. Config options/install instructions: https://knowledgebase.dnsadblock.com/how-to-install-and-configure-our-software/